# rename untitled in an Rstudio project

Tags: r, rstudio

So I create a project in R and I want to change the name in each tab of this project without saving its tab separate. Is there any way to rename just the tab of the project without save it?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: Renaming project folders doesn't impact the .Rproj file if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Are you referring to these tabs? https://i.imgur.com/Y22HChg.png

Comment: yes exactly. I want to change the names of these tabs without save them every time. @mhovd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name of an untitled notebook only by saving the file.